# Trying to replace characters with emotes, function goes nuts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, list

View code below. I'm kind of new to Javascript. As you can see what makes this function totally worthless is that everything inside well comment (which is the selected class) is interpreted as a string when running our function. Seems like I've run into a dead end. Any help to solve the problem is greatly appreciated.

```js
var doomDuck = {
   syntax: "doomDuck",
   url: "https://ny6rnw.bn1304.livefilestore.com/y2pXweBvaAhdSYJIdJbitWZO9tQZFzhfYMuLCyZJ-QN1pA2M_ktVuZL_mm00abCw9va84HOAHE0DpUit63mAppGnhtVrNUAhzWt6pAeh3hOPPg/image002.png?psid=1"
};

// tappedout emotes (more will be added)

var abc = {
   syntax: "abc",
   url: "abc>"
};

//Creates the list and adds all emote objects to it

var emoteList = [smile, sadFace, suprise, bored, chill, disappointed, wink, tongueWink, tongue, pirate, eyes, happy, angry, heart, monkeyLove, monkeyBored, monkeySir, monkeyInDifferent, monkeyMouthClosed, monkeyBandana, kappaHd, miniK, sandstorm, cross, fourHead, ANELE, ArsonNoSexy, AsianGlow, AtGL, AthenaPMS, Atlvy, AtWW, BabyRage, BatChest, BCWarrior, BibleThump, BigBrother, BionicBunion, BlargNaut, BloodTrail, BORT, BrainSlug, BrokeBack, BuddhaBar, CorgiDerp, CougarHunt, DAESuppy, DansGame, DatHass, DatSheffy, DBstyle, deExcite, deIlluminati, deShade, DogFace, EagleEye, EleGiggle, EvilFetus, FailFish, FPSMarksman, FrankerZ, FreakinStinkin, FUNgineer, FunRun, FuzzyOtterOO, GasJoker, GingerPower, GrammarKing, HassanChop, HeyGuys, HotPokket, HumbleLife, ItsBoshyTime, Jebaited, JKanStyle, JonCarnage, KAPOW, Kappa, Keepo, KevinTurtle, Kippa, Kreygasm, KZskull, MauFive, mcaT, MechaSupes, MrDestructoid, MVGame, NightBat, NinjaTroll, NoNoSpot, noScopeFourTwenty, NotAtk, OMGScoots, OneHand, OpieOP, OptimizePrime, OSbeaver, OSbury, OSdeo, OSfrog, OSkomodo, OSrob, OSsloth, panicBasket, PanicVis, PazPazowitz, PeoplesChamp, PermaSmug, PicoMause, PipeHype, PJHarley, PJSalt, PMSTwin, PogChamp, Poooound, Praiselt, PRChase, PunchTrees, RaccAttack, RalpherZ, RedCoat, ResidentSleeper, RitzMitz, RuleFive, Shazam, shazamicon, ShazBotstix, ShibeZ, SMOrc, SMSkull, SoBayed, SoonerLater, SriHead, SSSsss, StoneLightning, StrawBeary, SuperVinlin, SwiftRage, tbBaconBiscuit, tbChickenBiscuit, tbQuesarito, tbSausageBiscuit, tbSpicy, tbSriracha, TFTwoJohn, TheRinger, TheTarFu, TheThing, ThunBeast, TinyFace, TooSpicy, Trihard, TTours, UleetBackup, UncleNox, UnSane, Volcania, WholeWheat, WinWaker, WTRuck, WutFace, YouWHY, forsenRP, forsenBoys, sodaDS, sodaSENPAI, sodaRIP, sodaREKT, doomDuck];
emoteList.push();

for (var i = 0; i<emoteList.length; i++) {

 var tempRegObj = new RegExp(emoteList[i].syntax,"g");


      $(".well.comment>.add-img-responsive").html(function (_, html) {
         return html.replace(tempRegObj, "<img src='" + emoteList[i].url + "'/>")
      });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well  comment">
    <div class="row comment_header">
        <a class="comment-anchor" id="c2068395"></a>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h4>
                
                <a href="/users/blabla/">blablabla</a> says...
                
                <span class="pull-right">
                    
                    
                    
                    <a class="badge comment-page-id" href="#676575">#451</a>
                    
                </span>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="add-img-responsive">
    
    <p>Blablabla :) doomDuck</p>
    
    </div>
    <h6>
        May 6, 2015
        3:42 p.m.
    </h6>
</div>
```

Comment: We dont need to see each and every emote object, you could just show us a small sample. Having to scroll miles of definitions to get to your function code is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier if you rearrange your syntax, if that's alright.

Further, I would even use array shorthand notation to shorten this as much as I could.

The emote "syntax" is stored in `Emotes[0][n]` while the image url is `Emotes[1][n]`.

The only character you need to escape in your emotes now is `|`. The rest are escaped automatically when the regex is assembled.

The regex is created from a `"(" + Emotes[0].join("|") + ")"`.

Further, there's an additional bit that wraps alphanumeric entries (like Kappa) with word boundary markers so that "Skappa" won't register.

About case insensitivity: Since Array.indexOf is case sensitive, the easiest way, if you desire case insensitivity, would be to add a toLowerCase() at the end of the line building the regex, and another to the indexOf() in the callback function.

When a match is found, it uses a callback function to find the index of the match in the array.

```js
//robot emotes

var Emotes = [[],[]];

Emotes[0][0]=":)"
Emotes[1][0]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-ebf60cd72f7aa600-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][1]=":("
Emotes[1][1]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-d570c4b3b8d8fc4d-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][2]=":o"
Emotes[1][2]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-ae4e17f5b9624e2f-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][3]=":z"
Emotes[1][3]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-b9cbb6884788aa62-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][4]="B)"
Emotes[1][4]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-2cde79cfe74c6169-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][5]="://"
Emotes[1][5]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-374120835234cb29-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][6]=";)"
Emotes[1][6]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-cfaf6eac72fe4de6-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][7]=";p"
Emotes[1][7]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-3407bf911ad2fd4a-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][8]=":p"
Emotes[1][8]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-e838e5e34d9f240c-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][9]="R)"
Emotes[1][9]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-0536d670860bf733-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][10]="o_O"
Emotes[1][10]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-8e128fa8dc1de29c-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][11]=":D"
Emotes[1][11]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-9f2ac5d4b53913d7-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][12]=">("
Emotes[1][12]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-d31223e81104544a-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][13]="<3"
Emotes[1][13]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-577ade91d46d7edc-24x18.png"
Emotes[0][14]=":>"
Emotes[1][14]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-665aec4773011f44-27x42.png"
Emotes[0][15]=":]"
Emotes[1][15]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-fd30ca5440d03927-20x42.png"
Emotes[0][16]=":7"
Emotes[1][16]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-206849962fa002dd-29x24.png"
Emotes[0][17]=":\\|"
Emotes[1][17]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-d6e8b4f562b8f46f-20x18.png"
Emotes[0][18]=":s"
Emotes[1][18]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-f5428b0c125bf4a5-20x18.png"
Emotes[0][19]="#/"
Emotes[1][19]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/chansub-global-emoticon-39f51e122c6b2d60-27x18.png"
Emotes[0][20]="KappaHD"
Emotes[1][20]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/emoticon-2867-src-f02f9d40f66f0840-28x28.png"
Emotes[0][21]="MiniK"
Emotes[1][21]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/emoticon-2868-src-5a7a81bb829e1a4c-28x28.png"
Emotes[0][22]="duDudu"
Emotes[1][22]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/emoticon-23139-src-562e246a77bcb909-28x28.png"
Emotes[0][23]="riPepperonis"
Emotes[1][23]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/emoticon-23141-src-efb9caee5a110379-28x28.png"
Emotes[0][24]="4head"
Emotes[1][24]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/354/1.0"
Emotes[0][25]="ANELE"
Emotes[1][25]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/3792/1.0"
Emotes[0][26]="ArsonNoSexy"
Emotes[1][26]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/50/1.0"
Emotes[0][27]="AsianGlow"
Emotes[1][27]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/74/1.0"
Emotes[0][28]="AtGL"
Emotes[1][28]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/9809/1.0"
Emotes[0][29]="AthenaPMS"
Emotes[1][29]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/32035/1.0"
Emotes[0][30]="Atlvy"
Emotes[1][30]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/9800/1.0"
Emotes[0][31]="AtWW"
Emotes[1][31]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/9801/1.0"
Emotes[0][32]="BabyRage"
Emotes[1][32]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/22639/1.0"
Emotes[0][33]="BatChest"
Emotes[1][33]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1905/1.0"
Emotes[0][34]="BCWarrior"
Emotes[1][34]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/30/1.0"
Emotes[0][35]="BibleThump"
Emotes[1][35]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/86/1.0"
Emotes[0][36]="BigBrother"
Emotes[1][36]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1904/1.0"
Emotes[0][37]="BionicBunion"
Emotes[1][37]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/24/1.0"
Emotes[0][38]="BlargNaut"
Emotes[1][38]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/38/1.0"
Emotes[0][39]="BloodTrail"
Emotes[1][39]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/69/1.0"
Emotes[0][40]="BORT"
Emotes[1][40]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/243/1.0"
Emotes[0][41]="BrainSlug"
Emotes[1][41]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/881/1.0"
Emotes[0][42]="BrokeBack"
Emotes[1][42]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/4057/1.0"
Emotes[0][43]="BuddhaBar"
Emotes[1][43]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/27602/1.0"
Emotes[0][44]="CorgiDerp"
Emotes[1][44]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/49106/1.0"
Emotes[0][45]="CougarHunt"
Emotes[1][45]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/21/1.0"
Emotes[0][46]="DAESuppy"
Emotes[1][46]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/973/1.0"
Emotes[0][47]="DansGame"
Emotes[1][47]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/33/1.0"
Emotes[0][48]="DatHass"
Emotes[1][48]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/20225/1.0"
Emotes[0][49]="DatSheffy"
Emotes[1][49]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/170/1.0"
Emotes[0][50]="DBstyle"
Emotes[1][50]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/73/1.0"
Emotes[0][51]="deExcite"
Emotes[1][51]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/46249/1.0"
Emotes[0][52]="deIlluminati"
Emotes[1][52]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/46248/1.0"
Emotes[0][53]="deShade"
Emotes[1][53]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/46250/1.0"
Emotes[0][54]="DogFace"
Emotes[1][54]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1903/1.0"
Emotes[0][55]="EagleEye"
Emotes[1][55]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/20/1.0"
Emotes[0][56]="EleGiggle"
Emotes[1][56]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/4339/1.0"
Emotes[0][57]="EvilFetus"
Emotes[1][57]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/72/1.0"
Emotes[0][58]="FailFish"
Emotes[1][58]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/360/1.0"
Emotes[0][59]="FPSMarksman"
Emotes[1][59]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/42/1.0"
Emotes[0][60]="FrankerZ"
Emotes[1][60]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/65/1.0"
Emotes[0][61]="FreakinStinkin"
Emotes[1][61]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/39/1.0"
Emotes[0][62]="FUNgineer"
Emotes[1][62]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/244/1.0"
Emotes[0][63]="FunRun"
Emotes[1][63]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/48/1.0"
Emotes[0][64]="FuzzyOtterOO"
Emotes[1][64]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/168/1.0"
Emotes[0][65]="GasJoker"
Emotes[1][65]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/9802/1.0"
Emotes[0][66]="GingerPower"
Emotes[1][66]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/32/1.0"
Emotes[0][67]="GrammarKing"
Emotes[1][67]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/3632/1.0"
Emotes[0][68]="HassanChop"
Emotes[1][68]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/68/1.0"
Emotes[0][69]="HeyGuys"
Emotes[1][69]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/30259/1.0"
Emotes[0][70]="HotPokket"
Emotes[1][70]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/357/1.0"
Emotes[0][71]="HumbleLife"
Emotes[1][71]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/46881/1.0"
Emotes[0][72]="ItsBoshyTime"
Emotes[1][72]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/169/1.0"
Emotes[0][73]="Jebaited"
Emotes[1][73]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/90/1.0"
Emotes[0][74]="JKanStyle"
Emotes[1][74]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/15/1.0"
Emotes[0][75]="JonCarnage"
Emotes[1][75]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/26/1.0"
Emotes[0][76]="KAPOW"
Emotes[1][76]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/9803/1.0"
Emotes[0][77]="Kappa"
Emotes[1][77]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/25/1.0"
Emotes[0][78]="Keepo"
Emotes[1][78]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1902/1.0"
Emotes[0][79]="KevinTurtle"
Emotes[1][79]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/40/1.0"
Emotes[0][80]="Kippa"
Emotes[1][80]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1901/1.0"
Emotes[0][81]="Kreygasm"
Emotes[1][81]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/41/1.0"
Emotes[0][82]="KZskull"
Emotes[1][82]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/5253/1.0"
Emotes[0][83]="Mau5"
Emotes[1][83]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/30134/1.0"
Emotes[0][84]="mcaT"
Emotes[1][84]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/35063/1.0"
Emotes[0][85]="MechaSupes"
Emotes[1][85]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/9804/1.0"
Emotes[0][86]="MrDestructoid"
Emotes[1][86]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/28/1.0"
Emotes[0][87]="MVGame"
Emotes[1][87]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/29/1.0"
Emotes[0][88]="NightBat"
Emotes[1][88]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/9805/1.0"
Emotes[0][89]="NinjaTroll"
Emotes[1][89]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/45/1.0"
Emotes[0][90]="NoNoSpot"
Emotes[1][90]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/44/1.0"
Emotes[0][91]="noScope420"
Emotes[1][91]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/13084/1.0"
Emotes[0][92]="NotAtk"
Emotes[1][92]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/34875/1.0"
Emotes[0][93]="OMGScoots"
Emotes[1][93]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/91/1.0"
Emotes[0][94]="OneHand"
Emotes[1][94]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/66/1.0"
Emotes[0][95]="OpieOP"
Emotes[1][95]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/356/1.0"
Emotes[0][96]="OptimizePrime"
Emotes[1][96]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/16/1.0"
Emotes[0][97]="OSbeaver"
Emotes[1][97]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/47005/1.0"
Emotes[0][98]="OSbury"
Emotes[1][98]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/47420/1.0"
Emotes[0][99]="OSdeo"
Emotes[1][99]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/47007/1.0"
Emotes[0][100]="OSfrog"
Emotes[1][100]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/47008/1.0"
Emotes[0][101]="OSkomodo"
Emotes[1][101]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/47010/1.0"
Emotes[0][102]="OSrob"
Emotes[1][102]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/47302/1.0"
Emotes[0][103]="OSsloth"
Emotes[1][103]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/47011/1.0"
Emotes[0][104]="panicBasket"
Emotes[1][104]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/22998/1.0"
Emotes[0][105]="PanicVis"
Emotes[1][105]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/3668/1.0"
Emotes[0][106]="PazPazowitz"
Emotes[1][106]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/19/1.0"
Emotes[0][107]="PeoplesChamp"
Emotes[1][107]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/3412/1.0"
Emotes[0][108]="PermaSmog"
Emotes[1][108]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/27509/1.0"
Emotes[0][109]="PicoMause"
Emotes[1][109]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/27/1.0"
Emotes[0][110]="PipeHype"
Emotes[1][110]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/4240/1.0"
Emotes[0][111]="PJHarley"
Emotes[1][111]="hhttps://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/9808/1.0"
Emotes[0][112]="PJSalt"
Emotes[1][112]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/36/1.0"
Emotes[0][113]="PMSTwin"
Emotes[1][113]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/92/1.0"
Emotes[0][114]="PogChamp"
Emotes[1][114]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/88/1.0"
Emotes[0][115]="Poooound"
Emotes[1][115]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/358/1.0"
Emotes[0][116]="Praiselt"
Emotes[1][116]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/38586/1.0"
Emotes[0][117]="PRChase"
Emotes[1][117]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/28328/1.0"
Emotes[0][118]="PunchTrees"
Emotes[1][118]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/47/1.0"
Emotes[0][119]="RaccAttack"
Emotes[1][119]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/27679/1.0"
Emotes[0][120]="RalpherZ"
Emotes[1][120]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1900/1.0"
Emotes[0][121]="RedCoat"
Emotes[1][121]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/22/1.0"
Emotes[0][122]="ResidentSleeper"
Emotes[1][122]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/245/1.0"
Emotes[0][123]="RitzMitz"
Emotes[1][123]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/4338/1.0"
Emotes[0][124]="RuleFive"
Emotes[1][124]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/361/1.0"
Emotes[0][125]="Shazam"
Emotes[1][125]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/9807/1.0"
Emotes[0][126]="shazamicon"
Emotes[1][126]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/9806/1.0"
Emotes[0][127]="ShazBotstix"
Emotes[1][127]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/87/1.0"
Emotes[0][128]="ShibeZ"
Emotes[1][128]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/27903/1.0"
Emotes[0][129]="SMOrc"
Emotes[1][129]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/52/1.0"
Emotes[0][130]="SMSkull"
Emotes[1][130]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/51/1.0"
Emotes[0][131]="SoBayed"
Emotes[1][131]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1906/1.0"
Emotes[0][132]="SoonerLater"
Emotes[1][132]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/355/1.0"
Emotes[0][133]="SriHead"
Emotes[1][133]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/14706/1.0"
Emotes[0][134]="SSSsss"
Emotes[1][134]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/46/1.0"
Emotes[0][135]="StoneLightning"
Emotes[1][135]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/17/1.0"
Emotes[0][136]="StrawBeary"
Emotes[1][136]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/37/1.0"
Emotes[0][137]="SuperVinlin"
Emotes[1][137]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/31/1.0"
Emotes[0][138]="SwiftRage"
Emotes[1][138]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/34/1.0"
Emotes[0][139]="tbBaconBiscuit"
Emotes[1][139]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/44499/1.0"
Emotes[0][140]="tbBaconBiscuit"
Emotes[1][140]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/44498/1.0"
Emotes[0][141]="tbQuesarito"
Emotes[1][141]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/40863/1.0"
Emotes[0][142]="tbSausageBiscuit"
Emotes[1][142]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/44500/1.0"
Emotes[0][143]="tbSpicy"
Emotes[1][143]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/40864/1.0"
Emotes[0][144]="tbSriracha"
Emotes[1][144]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/40871/1.0"
Emotes[0][145]="TF2John"
Emotes[1][145]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1899/1.0"
Emotes[0][146]="TheRinger"
Emotes[1][146]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/18/1.0"
Emotes[0][147]="TheTarFu"
Emotes[1][147]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/70/1.0"
Emotes[0][148]="TheThing"
Emotes[1][148]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/7427/1.0"
Emotes[0][149]="ThunBeast"
Emotes[1][149]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1898/1.0"
Emotes[0][150]="TinyFace"
Emotes[1][150]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/67/1.0"
Emotes[0][151]="TooSpicy"
Emotes[1][151]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/359/1.0"
Emotes[0][152]="TriHard"
Emotes[1][152]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/171/1.0"
Emotes[0][153]="TTours"
Emotes[1][153]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/38436/1.0"
Emotes[0][154]="UleetBackup"
Emotes[1][154]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/49/1.0"
Emotes[0][155]="UncleNox"
Emotes[1][155]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/3666/1.0"
Emotes[0][156]="UnSane"
Emotes[1][156]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/71/1.0"
Emotes[0][157]="Volcania"
Emotes[1][157]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/166/1.0"
Emotes[0][158]="WholeWheat"
Emotes[1][158]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1896/1.0"
Emotes[0][159]="WinWaker"
Emotes[1][159]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/167/1.0"
Emotes[0][160]="WTRuck"
Emotes[1][160]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/1897/1.0"
Emotes[0][161]="WutFace"
Emotes[1][161]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/28087/1.0"
Emotes[0][162]="YouWHY"
Emotes[1][162]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/4337/1.0"
Emotes[0][163]="forsenRP"
Emotes[1][163]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/31100/1.0"
Emotes[0][164]="forsenBoys"
Emotes[1][164]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/31097/1.0"
Emotes[0][165]="sodaDS"
Emotes[1][165]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/16518/1.0"
Emotes[0][166]="sodaSENPAI"
Emotes[1][166]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/10920/1.0"
Emotes[0][167]="sodaRIP"
Emotes[1][167]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/28076/1.0"
Emotes[0][168]="sodaREKT"
Emotes[1][168]="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/28077/1.0"
Emotes[0][169]="doomDuck"
Emotes[1][169]="https://ny6rnw.bn1304.livefilestore.com/y2pXweBvaAhdSYJIdJbitWZO9tQZFzhfYMu…mm00abCw9va84HOAHE0DpUit63mAppGnhtVrNUAhzWt6pAeh3hOPPg/image002.png?psid=1"
Emotes[0][170]="abc"
Emotes[1][170]="abc>"

// custom emotes (create your own here)

Emotes.doomDuck = {syntax: "doomDuck",
   url: "https://ny6rnw.bn1304.livefilestore.com/y2pXweBvaAhdSYJIdJbitWZO9tQZFzhfYMuLCyZJ-QN1pA2M_ktVuZL_mm00abCw9va84HOAHE0DpUit63mAppGnhtVrNUAhzWt6pAeh3hOPPg/image002.png?psid=1"
};

// tappedout emotes (more will be added)

/*Emotes.abc = {syntax: "abc",
   url: "abc>"
};*/

var EmotesRE = new RegExp("(" + Emotes[0].join("|").replace(/([(){}\[\]*+?])/g,"\\$1").replace(/(^|\|)(\w+)(?=$|\|)/g,"$1\\b$2\\b")+ ")","g")

//Creates the list and adds all emote objects to it
$(".well.comment>.add-img-responsive").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(EmotesRE,function (match,p1) {
        return "<img src=\"" + Emotes[1][Emotes[0].indexOf(p1)] + "\" title=\"" + p1 + "\">"
    }))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well  comment">
    <div class="row comment_header">
        <a class="comment-anchor" id="c2068395"></a>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h4>
                
                <a href="/users/blabla/">blablabla</a> says...
                
                <span class="pull-right">
                    
                    
                    
                    <a class="badge comment-page-id" href="#676575">#451</a>
                    
                </span>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="add-img-responsive">
    
    WTRuck
  </div>
    <div class="add-img-responsive">
    
    <p>Blablabla :) Kappa Kappawordboundarytest KAPPA CASE INSENSITIVE TEST</p>
    
    </div>
    <h6>
        May 6, 2015
        3:42 p.m.
    </h6>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work great except that when I post another comment with another emote it is the same one as the one posted above. Is something wrong or have I missed something?

Comment: @josefholm should work fine now, updated my demo to reflect two comment sections so you can test right here.

Comment: Works better, unfortunately if I post another comment with only on emote it disappears. See: http://tappedout.net/mtg-decks/17-07-14-ftg-infect/ for live example. My wish is to make it work both on comments on decks and threads (ex. http://tappedout.net/mtg-forum/spoilers-rumors-and-speculation/modern-masters-2015-spoilers/). Haven't slept for two days, usually does better explanations than this.

Comment: @JosefHolm Either you've since fixed it, or I'm not understanding but all the comments there contain content. What should I be seeing? http://imgur.com/gQAz9TS.png

Comment: If I would post another comment with only BabyRage it would disappear completly even if you hit F12 or ctrl + u. Could it be the site itself causing this?

Comment: If the entire comment is disappearing (box and all), and it's not showing up in source code, it's definitely the site. I'm able to use emotes fine, in any try I've made, with my example code here.

Comment: As I thought. I have contacted the site admin. Another huge thanks for the help!